# Setting caBundle in MutatingWebhookConfiguration with Helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, installation, yaml, kubernetes-helm, ca

The `caBundle` for `MutatingWebhookConfiguration` is defined [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#webhookclientconfig-v1-admissionregistration-k8s-io) as:

> `caBundle` is a PEM encoded CA bundle which will be used to validate the webhook's server certificate. If unspecified, system trust roots on the apiserver are used.

I am getting the PEM encoded CA bundle with this command.

```sh
kubectl config view --raw --minify --flatten \ 
-o jsonpath='{.clusters[].cluster.certificate-authority-data}'
```

The resulting value is saved in a variable that is used in a `sed` command to replace the `CA_BUNDLE` string in a 'template' YAML as shown below.

```
apiVersion: admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: MutatingWebhookConfiguration
metadata:
  name: WEBHOOK_APP
  labels:
    app: WEBHOOK_APP
webhooks:
  - name: com.demo.NAMESPACE.WEBHOOK_APP
    sideEffects: None
    admissionReviewVersions: ["v1", "v1beta1"]
    matchPolicy: Equivalent
    failurePolicy: Fail
    clientConfig:
      caBundle: CA_BUNDLE
      service:
        name: WEBHOOK_APP
        namespace: NAMESPACE
        path: "/mutate"
    rules:
      - operations: [ "CREATE", "UPDATE" ]
        apiGroups: [""]
        apiVersions: ["v1"]
        resources: ["pods"]
        scope: "*"
```

What is the way in Helm chart to pass on the `CA_BUNDLE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading variable dirctly from env variable in your helm chart is not possible due to security reasons and this functionality was not implemented as states in [this document](https://github.com/technosophos/k8s-helm/blob/master/docs/charts_tips_and_tricks.md#know-your-template-functions).

In helm chart you can always create a variable e.g. `myCAbundleVariable` in `values.yaml` file that will be holding your PEM encoded CA and then use value from this variable in chart like this:

```
webhooks:
  - ...
    clientConfig:
      caBundle: {{ .myCAbundleVariable }}
```

If you want to pass the value 'in runtime' when running helm command you can use `--set` parameter.

So your helm command would look like this:

```
helm install ... --set myCAbundleVariable=$(kubectl config view --raw --minify --flatten \
-o jsonpath='{.clusters[].cluster.certificate-authority-data}')`
```

Let me know if it was helpful.